# How do I include html / css in my shiny app

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

below is the shiny app, if I need to add some css into it (attached below), where can i add it so that it renders in r shiny app

css

```
<style>
    .bs-example{
        margin: 60px;
    }
</style>
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(

    titlePanel("Stateful"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(

        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
            tabsetPanel(
                id="inTabset",
                tabPanel("Tab 1",actionButton("switch_tab", "Go to the third tab")),
                tabPanel("Tab 2", "there!"),
                tabPanel("Tab 3", "there!"))

        )
    )
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

})
```

Comment: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add your CSS file in the ui section, like below:

```
tags$head(
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "style.css")
  )
```

Keep in mind your CSS file should be in the www directory in your shiny app.